# Insert image file to publisher document in place of existing image

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-interop, ms-publisher

I have publisher document used as template.

[image]

How to insert image from file in place of "?" image.

Probably it's same way as for MS Word but I can't find out.

I access that template this way:

```
using Publisher = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Publisher;

Publisher._Application pubApp = new Publisher.Application();
Publisher.Document doc = pubApp.Open(docPath);
Publisher.Page templateCard = doc.Pages[1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically:

```
shape.PictureFormat.Replace(filePath);
```

Best way to find my template image I figured out is set alternative text to my image and just chack it:

```
foreach (Publisher.Shape shape in currenPage.Shapes) {
    if (shape.AlternativeText == "DICKBUTT")
        //here you do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Well done! You might also just set the .Name property of the shape from VBA and check for that (that's generally the easiest way to identify a shape in Publisher code).